# What is the best way to update another table based on a certain condition ON UPDATE?

Tags: mysql

I'm having two tables `subscription` and `subscription_event`. A `subscription_event` can be one of the following types:

```java
public enum SubscriptionEventType {

    CREATED,
    CANCELED,
    CHARGED_SUCCESSFULLY,
    CHARGED_UNSUCCESSFULLY,
    EXPIRED,
    TRIAL_STARTED,
    TRIAL_ENDED,
    WENT_ACTIVE, // Subscription went active and can be charged from now on.
    WENT_PAST_DUE;

    public Long getValue() {
        return this.ordinal() + 1L;
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to keep the state of `subscription` to the most recent event. The problem: Those events do not come in correct order. E.g. it is possible to get a `CHARGED_SUCCESSFULLY` event *before* a `WENT_ACTIVE` event.

So there are several way how I can accomplish what I need. First of all I can check the condition in my application layer and always set that "most recent" state based on the timestamp of the event.

```java
Long subscriptionId = lastRecordedEvent.getSubscriptionId();

if(event.getTimestamp() > lastRecordedEvent.getTimestamp()) {
    // Since the current event is more recent than all other events
    // we also have to update the subscription state
    subscriptionRepository.updateState(subscriptionId, event.getTimestamp());
}
```

However, I do not want to do this in my application layer. Another solution would be to use a `TRIGGER` on the `subscription_event` table and let that on decide whether to update the relevant `subscription` or not. The reason why I do not go for that just yet is because I know that triggers can be easily forgotten and also be a pain to maintain. Also I know one should take every other option into account before using a `TRIGGER` but since I am not a SQL/MySQL expert I'm not aware of all my options here.

So what would be the most practicable way to keep `subscription` up-to-date in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert your event as usual into the table and then execute the following

```
UPDATE subscriptions set state=events.state
FROM subscriptions inner join events on subscriptions.id = events.subscriptionID
Where events.SubscriptionId = ? and events.Timestamp = 
   (select max(timestamp) from events where events.SubscriptionId = ?)
```

You will need to pass parameters for the two `?`s to be the subscription id of the event you just inserted

**EDIT**

An alternative approach is rather than have a status field in the database, create a view for your subscriptions and always query the view instead.

```
CREATE VIEW vw_subscriptions as
  Select s.id, otherfields from subscription, coalesce(e.Status, 1) as status
  from subscriptions s left outer join events e on s.id=e.subscriptionId
  AND e.timestamp = 
   (select max(timestamp) from events where subscriptionId=s.id)
```

If you are worried about forgetting/maintaining the SQL or triggers, document them as comments in your repository functions and maintain all changes to the database as a change script that you store with your source code.  That way your changes are all in your source control.

Comment: The problem I'm having with this approach is that it actually feels like as if I'd do that basically in my application layer. There is a chance that this statement can be forgotten at some point which is why I thought maybe it would be better to use a `TRIGGER` in this case. Executing this additional statement is not so much different than the `if` condition I'm having in my question. Is that really the safest way to avoid mistakes here?

Comment: The danger I see here is that I'm using the repository-pattern. If somebody else has the idea to write another method that inserts a `subscription_event` he might forget to do the update on `subscription`. Since all this is part of a payment system implementation I want to make sure that the state of a subscription cannot so easily be messed up.

Comment: @displayname You implement this SQL call in your repository, if another method inserts a subscription event the next time your function is called it will fix this issue.

Comment: @displayname The advantage of using this SQL is that if another process or thread inserts an event into the database in the middle of your update, the SQL will make sure the subscription status is correct.  Otherwise you could retrieve the last event timestamp, another process updates and then you are updating based on stale data.  Yes the trigger is best, but if you want the code in one place this is the next best thing

Comment: Would you personally go for the trigger or would you prefer the "code in one place" option? My problem is that I simply cannot decide what's the better option here ^^

Comment: @displayname It really is personal choice.  I've updated my answer with the alternative, which is to use a view, which has the advantage of only storing the status once, but may lead to performance issues. My personal choice is the view, I prefer store once, if I started seeing performance problems I'd then fall back on the trigger. I could then update the view to be a straight table query without needing to change the application code.

Comment: Thank you! That sounds reasonable. I'd play around a bit with that view solution! Thanks for sharing your insights! :)